# How to send REST request to local cluster?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, kubernetes

Hello I have a spring boot web application. I dockerized my web application and I want to deploy my application to local kubernetes cluster by using minikube. Lastly I want to access my REST endpoint from local kubernetes cluster.
Here is my simple REST API function:

```
@RestController
public class SampleController {

    @RequestMapping("/x")
    public String example(){
        return "hello world";
    }
}
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM eclipse-temurin:17
ARG JAR_FILE=target/k8s-example-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.1'
services:
  app:
    container_name: first-docker-container
    restart: always
    image: first-docker-image
    build: ./
    ports:
      - "8082:8080"
```

When I run "docker build -t first-docker-image ." and "docker-compose up" commands, I can send REST request to "localhost:8082/x" endpoint without any error.

deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: first-kubernetes-example
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: first-kubernetes-example
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: first-kubernetes-example
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: first-kubernetes-example
          image: first-docker-image
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8082
```

service.yml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service-with-nodeport
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
    - port: 9090
      targetPort: 8082
      nodePort: 30008
      protocol: "TCP"
  selector:
    app: first-kubernetes-example
```

```
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
kubectl apply -f service.yml
```

After I run at the above commands, I can see that my web application deployed to kubernetes pod successfully.

Here is the output of "kubectl get services" command:

```
NAME                       TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes                 ClusterIP   10.96.0.1       <none>        443/TCP          122m
my-service-with-nodeport   NodePort    10.104.11.180   <none>        9090:30008/TCP   121m
```

My minikube ip is 192.168.59.2
I cannot get response from "192.168.59.2:30008/x" endpoint. How can I solve this issue ?
Thanks your help.

NOTE: I don't want to do port-forwarding.

Comment: Are you trying to access your deployment from the remote host or locally?

Comment: I try to access my deployment locally

Comment: Try to run `minikube service my-service-with-nodeport --url` and then navigate to the result

Comment: It did not work. Basically, I followed this article step by step. In the article, there is no need to run your command. 
https://medium.com/@javatechie/kubernetes-tutorial-run-deploy-spring-boot-application-in-k8s-cluster-using-yaml-configuration-3b079154d232